# Ajax actionlink stops working when adding [HttpPost] to the action method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

The ajax actionlink looks like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create account", "RegisterNewUser", "RegisteredUsers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "actionButtons" }
```

And when the RegisterNewUser Action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(uName, email, password))
        {
            msg = "The provided email already exists";
        }

        ViewBag.DeniedMsg = msg;
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

The ajax actionlink works fine. But when I add `[HttpPost]` to the action method (that by the way is called by the ajax actionlink) the link stops responding. Nothing happens when I click on it. What am I doing wrong? The form that contains the link looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "registerForm" }))
    { 
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nickName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nickName, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
        <br /><br />            

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls", id = "firstPassword" })
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
        <br /><br /><br />
        <hr style="color: #D5E0EE; border: solid; border-style: double;" />

        @Ajax.ActionLink("Create account", "RegisterNewUser", "RegisteredUsers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "actionButtons" })
        <br /><br />
        <p style="color: red">@ViewBag.DeniedMsg</p>
    }
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `@Ajax.ActionLink()` inside a form? And is `RegisterNewUser()` a GET or POST method? What is it you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to post the form data using the Ajax extensions you need to change your form to use an `Ajax.BeginForm` and replace the button with a submit button:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterNewUser", "RegisteredUsers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }))    
{
  ....form data
   <input type="submit" value="Create account" />

}
```

Also make sure you include the `updaterDiv` within the form.

You will need to add the `[HttpPost]` to your controller action, and I would also change it to take the model that you have in your original view as the posted parameter too.